# Help! Why does my curly brace show as a straight line?

Tags: tikz-pgf, brackets, braces

I'm a beginner at latex and I've been reading everything I found about curl braces. I managed to positioned it where I wanted it but now my curly brace appears as a straight line. When I write the code in a new different file with just this diagram, the curly brace shows, only in another position. what can I do to fix it? Thanks!!

```
 \documentclass{beamer}
 \usetheme{Frankfurt}
 \setbeamercovered{transparent}
 \usepackage{pgf,tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows, automata}

 \begin{document}
    \scalebox{1.1}
    {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [node distance= 1cm,auto,
    every node/.style={text=white,rounded corners=0.05cm},
    grande/.style={rectangle,  fill=green!60!blue, font=\large, minimum width= 7cm, minimum height=0.8cm},
    peque/.style={rectangle, fill=green!30!black, font=\large, minimum width=3.5cm, minimum height= 0.4cm}]

    \node[grande, xshift=1.5cm]  (oracion){Oración};
    \node[grande, below of=oracion] (evento) {Evento};
    \node[grande, below of=evento] (EPA) {EPA};

    \node[peque, below of= EPA, anchor=east, minimum width=3.5cm](syntax){Sintaxis};
    \node[peque, right=0.03cm of syntax,minimum width=3.5cm](semantics){Semántica};
    \node[peque, below of=syntax, yshift=0.4cm](funciones){\scriptsize F. sintácticas};
    \node[peque, right=0.03cm of funciones, minimum width=1.73cm, yshift=0cm](roles){\tiny R. temáticos};
    \node[peque, right=0.03cm of roles, minimum width=1.73cm](rasgos){\tiny R. semánticos};

    \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt},xshift=-0.5cm,yshift=-5cm] (-2,1.0) -- (-2,2.5) node [black,midway,xshift=-0.6cm, yshift=0cm]  {\footnotesize Diátesis};

    \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. Please, can you edit your code and can you add the \documentclass used? Thank you.

Comment: @Sebastiano Judging from the second line of the code, I think the OP is using `beamer`.

Comment: @JouleV I agree with you. I thinked that beamer could to contain also any options with the brackets [].

Comment: @JouleV Exactly , it is a beamer presentation. Sorry about that guys! I'll edit now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to load `decorations.pathreplacing` library to use the decoration.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
 \setbeamercovered{transparent}
 \usepackage{pgf,tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows, automata, decorations.pathreplacing}

 \begin{document}
    \scalebox{1.1}
    {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [node distance= 1cm,auto,
    every node/.style={text=white,rounded corners=0.05cm},
    grande/.style={rectangle,  fill=green!60!blue, font=\large, minimum width= 7cm, minimum height=0.8cm},
    peque/.style={rectangle, fill=green!30!black, font=\large, minimum width=3.5cm, minimum height= 0.4cm}]

    \node[grande, xshift=1.5cm]  (oracion){Oración};
    \node[grande, below of=oracion] (evento) {Evento};
    \node[grande, below of=evento] (EPA) {EPA};

    \node[peque, below of= EPA, anchor=east, minimum width=3.5cm](syntax){Sintaxis};
    \node[peque, right=0.03cm of syntax,minimum width=3.5cm](semantics){Semántica};
    \node[peque, below of=syntax, yshift=0.4cm](funciones){\scriptsize F. sintácticas};
    \node[peque, right=0.03cm of funciones, minimum width=1.73cm, yshift=0cm](roles){\tiny R. temáticos};
    \node[peque, right=0.03cm of roles, minimum width=1.73cm](rasgos){\tiny R. semánticos};

    \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt},xshift=-0.5cm,yshift=-5cm] (-2,1.0) -- (-2,2.5) node [black,midway,xshift=-0.6cm, yshift=0cm]  {\footnotesize Diátesis};

    \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

off-topic (sine your main problem is solved by [@JouleV](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483190/help-why-does-my-curly-brace-show-as-a-straight-line/483192#483192) answer), but it can be helpful:

- image is enclosed in `frame` environment (since you use `beamer` document class
- for positioning of nodes is used syntax from the `positioning` packages
- used are only relative coordinates,
- nodes are in two chains
- in nodes are used only two different font sizes and their definition is moved inside nodes styles
- for brace is used `calligraphic brace` defined in the package `calligraphy`

  ```
  \documentclass{beamer}
  \usetheme{Frankfurt}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows, automata,
                  calc, chains,
                  decorations.pathreplacing,
                  calligraphy,
                  positioning}

  \begin{document}
  \begin{frame}[fragile]
  \frametitle{My image}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[
       node distance = 2mm and 1mm,
         start chain = A going right,
         start chain = B going above,
         base/.style = {rounded corners=0.5mm, text=white},
       grande/.style = {base, fill=green!60!blue, font=\large,
                        minimum width=87mm, minimum height=8mm,
                        on chain=B},
   peque/.style args = {#1/#2}{base, fill=green!30!black,
                               minimum width=#1, minimum height= 5mm,
                               font=#2,
                               on chain=A},
           BC/.style = {decorate,
              decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=5pt,
              pre =moveto, pre  length=1pt,
              post=moveto, post length=1pt,
              raise=5pt}, % for mirroring of brace
              very thick,
              pen colour=black},
                         ]
  \node[peque=43mm/\scriptsize]   (funciones) {F. sintácticas};
  \node[peque=21mm/\scriptsize]               {R. temáticos};
  \node[peque=21mm/\scriptsize]               {R. semánticos};
  \node[peque=43mm/\large,
        above=of funciones]       (syntax)    {Sintaxis};
  \node[peque=43mm/\large]        (semantics) {Semántica};
  \node[grande,
        above=of $(syntax.north)!0.5!(semantics.north)$]  {EPA};
  \node[grande]   {Evento};
  \node[grande]   {Oración};
  %
  \draw[BC]   (funciones.south west) --
            node[left=9pt,font=\footnotesize] {Diátesis}
              (syntax.north west);
      \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{frame}
  ```

[image]